# Sonar not picking up clover test results created by running maven in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, clover

I've been working on this all day and haven't been able to find a solution, so thought i'd turn to the stackoverflow community.

I have a server setup with Jenkins (version 1.454). It's configured to perform the build with Maven (version 3.0.4). The build command is as follows:

```
clean clover2:setup verify clover2:aggregate clover2:clover
```

Jenkins has the sonar plugin installed and configured. My sonar install (version 3) is on a different server to jenkins. After the build is completed, i can see the results on sonar (the basics of the build).

I have installed to sonar the clover plugin (sonar-clover-plugin-2.8.jar) manually by putting it into the 'extentions/plugins' folder. It appeared in sonar and I can configure it. I put in the license, version (3.1.4) and sonar.clover.reportPath as "target\site\clover\clover.xml".

When I run the build, it is successful as before, and I can see the basic results as before in Sonar, however, I cannot see any test code coverage results.
When I look at the maven build output I notice the following:

```
[INFO] Writing report to '/opt/jenkins/jobs/foo/workspace/target/site/clover/clover.xml'
```

and then near the bottom of the output:

```
[INFO] [15:08:36.586] Clover XML report not found
```

The following are also in my pom:

```
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.clover.reportPath>target\site\clover\clover.xml</sonar.clover.reportPath>
    <sonar.surefire.reportsPath>target\surefire-reports</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
    <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>clover</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
    <sonar.clover.version>${clover.version}</sonar.clover.version>
```

When I look on the jenkins box, I can see that it has generated the clover.xml file (infact in my fiddling I have the clover plugin working on jenkins, so i can see the results there!).

I'm guessing at this stage that there is some issue with jenkins and sonar being on seperate boxes.
Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot more fiddling around, it appeared that I needed to change the following:

```
<sonar.clover.reportPath>${project.build.directory}/site/clover/clover.xml</sonar.clover.reportPath>
    <sonar.surefire.reportsPath>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
```

A good reference was the following:
[all about pom variables](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html)